# Why synchronizing an ArrayList directly ensures its visibility to other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I was concerned in making sure other threads will still see the changes made by one of the threads to

```
static ArrayList<aClass> list = new ArrayList<aClass>();
```

I used to use *volatile* with *list* in attempt to ensure visibility but it's not right since it doesn't really affect the *aClass* elements of the list.

My understanding to *volatile* is [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html).

Luckily I say, I *synchronized* all the reads and writes to *list*, which happen by using an iterator

```
Iterator<aClass> iter = list.iterator(); 
        while( iter.hasNext() ) {
            aClass aClassReference = iter.next();
            ...
```

Now I don't use *volatile* to ensures visibility; I accounted on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083000/is-iterating-over-a-list-retrieved-in-a-synchronized-block-thread-safe). In that question, the OP didn't use volatile, only synchronized, and the answer stated that

> values added by thread become visible for all other threads, that enter synchronized block

I felt comfortable with Synchronized because of that answer. I understand that *synchronized* ensures that no 2 reads/writes from different threads can happen simultaneously but why does it ensure visibility among threads ?

Comment: To guarantee visibility of array elements we have to rely on mechanisms like synchronized keyword, atomic variables, or ReentrantLock.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791805/garbage-collection-and-synchronized-visibility).

I didn't realized it's answered until I wrote the question and see the suggestion by SO.